# WARNING-[UIApplication delegate] must be used from main thread only

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting warning [UIApplication delegate] must be used from main thread only in the below line of code

> ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
>   delegate]).loginProfile.accessToken;

Following is my code.

```
+ (NSString *)accessTokenHashForDate:(NSDate *)date withParameters:(NSArray *)params{

    NSString *accessToken = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).loginProfile.accessToken;

    NSString *paramsStr = [params componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    NSString *hashStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", [CommonUtil IMEI], [date agileHashFormattedString], (!paramsStr) ? @"" : paramsStr, accessToken];
    return hashStr
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove this warning message?

Comment: first of all you should not keep login profile on app delegate.

Comment: @Lu_I agree with you but this is legacy code and right now I do not want to change it.

Comment: so the only way is to use app delegate on main thread, use blocks to return hashStr because it will be async, any way it will be a lot of refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (NSString *)accessTokenHashForDate:(NSDate *)date withParameters:(NSArray *)params{
__block NSString *accessToken = NULL;
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        accessToken = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).loginProfile.accessToken;


} else {
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        accessToken = ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).loginProfile.accessToken;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}
NSString *paramsStr = [params componentsJoinedByString:@""];
           NSString *hashStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", [CommonUtil IMEI], [date agileHashFormattedString], (!paramsStr) ? @"" : paramsStr, accessToken];
return hashStr;
```

}

Comment: There is a much simpler solution than using semaphores. Get rid of the semaphore use and replace `dispatch_async` with `dispatch_sync`.